# Cannot access APIs when add IHostedService service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I use `.NET 6` and when I add an IHostedService service in ASP.NET Core, I cannot access the APIs. If I remove the IHostedService, I can access the APIs.

Add IHostedService:

```
//builder.Services.AddHostedService<WSService>();
builder.WebHost.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddHostedService<WSService>());
```

```
public class WSService : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("back ground task");
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

If add IHostedService, cannot access http://localhost:5000/Query

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class QueryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IQueryData _queryData;

        public QueryController(IQueryData queryData)
        {
            _queryData = queryData;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Query([FromQuery] QueryDataRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var data = await _queryData.PagingQueryAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            return new JsonResult(data);
        }

    }
}
```

Add IHostedService will not print these logs, it seems the WebHost is not running
[image]

So, how to resolve this problem, thanks!

Comment: Derive from [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) instead of implementing `IHostedService` and put your code into `ExecuteAsync()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are causing an infinite loop on your `StartAsync` method, and as noted by the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#startasync):

> StartAsync should be limited to short running tasks because hosted services are run sequentially, and no further services are started until StartAsync runs to completion.